# How to make a distance plot in bokeh that is similar to seaborn's?

Tags: python, data-visualization, bokeh

Maybe I am blind but I can't seem to find a clean way of creating a distance plot in bokeh like in seaborn.

Looked around in the docs. Nothing truly explicit.

Here is an example of some seaborn code to create a distance plot.

```
    # Example code
    # Set general graph info
    sns.set(style="whitegrid")
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    plt.title("Distance Plot: " + col_feature_name)

    # Create seaborn graph
    sns.distplot(df[col_feature_name].dropna())

    plt.show()
    plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: I know it's a dumb question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try with these examples from the docs https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/histogram.html and https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.11.0/docs/gallery/density.html

Comment: Well, that was embarrassing...thank you

Answer (score 2):

That link in the comment goes to a *very* old Bokeh version, and uses an MPL compat layer that was long-removed. Bokeh is not a "high level" API. Bokeh can draw that plot easily, but you would need to compute the data for it. For a high level API on top of Bokeh, look at [Holoviews](https://holoviews.org/) or [Chartify](https://github.com/spotify/chartify).